# Print não retorna valores tabela

Tags: array, lua

```
pokecatches = {
["Bulbasaur"] = {chance = 150, corpse = 5969},
["Ivysaur"] = {chance = 275, corpse = 5982},
["Venusaur"] = {chance = 400, corpse = 5962},
}
print(table.maxn(pokecatches))
corpses = {}
for x=1, table.maxn(pokecatches) do
table.insert(corpses, pokecatches[x].corpse)
end
print(table.concat(corpses, ","))
io.read()
```

Esse trecho deveria adicionar o valor corpse a tabela corpses, mas não vai, o print(table.man(pokecatches)) retorna 0. Alguem sabe porque?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você quer iterar num *set* como se fosse uma tabela simples.

Uma possibilidade de ajustar o código é reestruturar os dados como tabela, para iterar por índice numérico (`pokecatches[x])`:

```
pokecatches = {
   { name = "Bulbasaur", chance = 150, corpse = 5969},
   { name = "Ivysaur"  , chance = 275, corpse = 5982},
   { name = "Venusaur" , chance = 400, corpse = 5962},
}
print(table.maxn(pokecatches))
corpses = {}
for x=1, table.maxn(pokecatches) do
   table.insert(corpses, pokecatches[x].corpse)
end
print(table.concat(corpses, ","))
```

A outram para manter o uso de *sets*, é iterar com `for .. in` para obter os dados de chave e valor com `pair`:

```
pokecatches = {
   ["Bulbasaur"] = {chance = 150, corpse = 5969},
   ["Ivysaur"] = {chance = 275, corpse = 5982},
   ["Venusaur"] = {chance = 400, corpse = 5962},
}

corpses = {}
for name, data in pairs(pokecatches) do
   table.insert(corpses, data.corpse)
end
print(table.concat(corpses, ","))
```

> Veja os dois funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/GJoFII)**

Comment: Achei mais viavel usar a segunda opção, ja que a tabela tem mais de 300 elementos. Obrigado.