# Tamanho do array

Tags: array, lua, lua-table

Como pego o tamanho de um array com essa estrutura:

```
A = {
    ["b"] = {c=1, d=2},
    ["e"] = {f=1, g=2},
}
```

Quero pegar o tamanho de A, nesse caso, 2.

Comment: Esse [**link**](http://www.lua.org/pil/19.1.html) deve ajudar.

Comment: Para que você precisa desse tamanho?

Comment: @lhf para que você precisa desta pergunta?

Comment: @Bacco, porque eu nunca precisei saber o tamanho de uma tabela. Eu estou tentando saber qual o problema real que o OP está tentando resolver.

Comment: @lhf Então, mas parece que o Gabriel precisa hehehehe. Só fiz a pergunta no mesmo tom pra demonstrar a estranheza inicial que a pergunta causa. Mas é bom saber que o "pai da matéria" está de olho nas questões de Lua aqui conosco ;) Quanto à pergunta do Gabriel, suponho estar relacionada a essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31288/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lua tem tabelas e não *arrays*. As tabelas de Lua tem semântica de *array* e semântica de *hash* dependendo de como você coloca seus elementos, e isto pode ser um pouco confuso.

Um *array* precisa ter um índice inteiro sequencial preferencialmente iniciando em 1. O tamanho é definido pela quantidade de elementos. **Se** realmente é um *array* e iniciar em 1, sabemos que o maior índice corresponde ao tamanho da tabela. Mas o que você está tentando verificar no exemplo é o tamanho de uma estrutura de *hashs* e não um *array*.

Tem algumas soluções possíveis dependendo do seu objetivo.

```
table.getn(A)
```

ou

```
#A
```

Esta é a solução mais óbvia mas pode trazer resultados diferentes do que você espera se tiver algum elemento `nil` no meio da tabela. Ele conta a quantidade de elementos até encontrar um `nil`. O segundo é o operador de *length*. Se você puder garantir que você tem um *array* e não um *hash* isto pode funcionar.

```
table.maxn(A)
```

Esta forma retorna o maior índice possível na tabela. Pode ser a solução que deseja dependendo da constituição da tabela. Se não contiver elementos nulos na tabela isto se confunde com o total de elementos. Funciona melhor para tabelas que são *hashs*. Não é o foco do título da sua pergunta mas é o que você está efetivamente usando. Você tem primariamente um *hash* e não um *array*. É bom entender a diferença.

```
function table.map_length(t)
    local c = 0
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
         c = c+1
    end
    return c
end
```

Este algoritmo conta todos os elementos em uma tabela que possa ter índices arbitrários. Também funciona bem para *hashs*. Estas soluções podem ser mais garantidas se você não tem certeza absoluta que tem um *array* em mãos. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377694/221800).

Teste com [seu exemplo no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2pGNeF). Não coloco exemplos dos outros porque eles não vão retornar o resultado esperado para o seu exemplo.

```
function table.map_length(t)
    local c = 0
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
         c = c+1
    end
    return c
end
 
A = {
["b"] = {c=1, d=2},
["e"] = {f=1, g=2},
}
 
print(table.map_length(A))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jNlaop). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/imcdrymr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/TableLength.lua).

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado, vou estudar mais