# Loop com array + string

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

Estou tentando fazer algo como:

```
a = {move1="oi", move2="oi2"}
for x=1, #a do
print(a.move..x)
end
```

Não sei explicar muito bem, mas o que estou tentando é isso:

```
print(a.move..x)
```

ficando `print(a.move1)` e no próximo `print(a.move2)`, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vou colocar duas soluções para você.

A primeira é baseada em [resposta que eu já lhe forneci](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33301/101). Preste muita atenção ao comentário do [lhf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1642/lhf), o criador da linguagem.

```
function table.map_length(t)
    local c = 0
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
         c = c + 1
    end
    return c
end

a =  { move1 = "oi", move2 = "oi2"}

for x=1, table.map_length(a) do
    print(a["move" .. x])
end
```

Para ajudar entender saiba que a tabela que você escreveu é a mesma coisa que escrever:

```
a =  { ["move1"] = "oi", ["move2"] = "oi2"}
```

A sintaxe de `a.move1` é o mesmo que `a["move1"]`. Aí você consegue o que você quer.

A segunda é o jeito correto de fazer o que você quer.

```
a =  { move1 = "oi", move2 = "oi2"}

for k, v in pairs(a) do
    print(v)
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2ee3eA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ndrulnuy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/PrintMap.lua).

---

Uma observação importante: em todos os seus códigos você ignora a indentação em todas as linguagens que você está tentando. Isso dificulta a sua leitura e principalmente das outras pessoas. Pode parecer bobo, mas os melhores programadores do mundo têm dificuldade para ler códigos não indentados. Existe uma dificuldade cognitiva no jeito como você escreve. E não é só isto, espaçamentos em geral ajudam a leitura. Veja a diferença como eu escrevi.

Comment: Vou começar a me preocupar mais com isso. Quanto a resposta, está perfeita.