# Como colocar variáveis dentro de vetores?

Tags: c++, struct, array, hashmap

Como faço para criar variáveis dentro de um vetor?

Algo como:

```
int arr[] = {int x=1, int y = 2};
```

Comment: `struct` te atenderia?

Comment: Por favor, crie uma resposta.

Comment: Dei uma resposta para começar te ajudar. Se você tiver dúvidas específicas sobre o uso de `struct` e quem sabe posteriormente `unordered_map`, você vai perguntando. Reforço que você deve tentar aprender primeiro como fazer o básico do C++ que é o uso de `struct`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você não pode fazer isso do jeito que você faz com Lua (que a linguagem que você costuma perguntar mais aqui). C++ é uma linguagem estática e tem características bem diferentes do que você está acostumado.

Ou você cria uma [`struct`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)) ou você cria uma estrutura própria que mapeia valores tendo algumas opções.

## Mapa de valores

Provavelmente para conseguir algo mais próximo do que você obtém em Lua deveria usar uma estrutura pronta da biblioteca padrão chamada [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Com esta estrutura você pode criar elementos como quiser como uma *string* e guardar valores nela.

[Lembra disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38912/loop-com-array-string)? Funciona da mesma forma só que em C++ não tem a facilidade da sintaxe que uma *string* era tratada como se fosse variável. Tem que usar só com sintaxe de *string*. No fundo Lua implementa igual a esta estrutura do C++ (claro do jeito dela), mas faz exatamente a mesma coisa.

Exemplo:

```
//declara a variável do tipo unordered com chave do tipo string e valor do tipo int
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> exemplo;
exemplo["x"] = 1; //criou um elemento chamado "x" que vale 1
exemplo["y"] = 2;
//acessar
cout << exemplo["x"] //imprime 1
```

Esta estrutura está disponível na biblioteca padrão à partir do C++11. Em versões anteriores da linguagem precisa usar uma biblioteca externa ou fazer uma estrutura assim por conta própria, o que é bem difícil fazer certo.

Note que em C++ tudo precisa ter tipo definido. Até tem como fazer para aceitar qualquer tipo mas precisa usar uma estrutura própria para isso também.

C++, ao contrário de Lua, tem essas coisas que dão mais trabalho. Em compensação ela é muito mais rápida, poderosa e segura. Dá para fazer em C++ tudo o que dá para fazer em Lua, só que às vezes dá mais trabalho.

## `Struct`

Mas o mais comum em C++ é evitar isso quanto puder e usar algo estático, resolvido em tempo de compilação, no caso o melhor é usar uma [`struct`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/).

Aí você faz assim:

```
//declara a composição da estrutura para ser usada depois
struct estrutura {
    int x;
    int y;
}
//cria a variável exemplo do tipo estrutura e guarda os valores nos seus elementos
estrutura exemplo = { 1, 2 };
//acessar
cout << exemplo.x; //imprime 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/StructBasic.cpp).

É um pouco mais complicado que isso mas já é um começo para você começar estudar o assunto.

Esta forma não é exatamente igual ao resultado que você obtém com Lua mas é o mais comum, é o que se tenta fazer em primeiro lugar quando está programando em C++. Você não deveria procurar outra forma até que realmente seja necessário. Procure sempre o mais simples e em C ou C++ uma `struct` é o que seja chama mais idiomático, mais próximo da cultura da linguagem.

## Qual usar

Aprenda usar bem `struct`. Mesmo que ela tem alguma limitação, na imensa maioria dos casos é ela ou sua variação `class` é que você deverá usar. Quando aprender mais e chegar em um ponto que precisa de mais dinamismo você pensará em usar uma estrutura como a `unordered_map` que tem a vantagem de colocar, tirar e acessar elementos dinamicamente (em tempo de execução) mas tem performance ruim para os padrões do C++ e não consegue verificação em tempo de compilação. Isso vai contra a filosofia do C++.

Comment: Entendi. Estou estudando C/C++ exatamente para entender melhor como realmente funcionam as coisas.

Comment: Obrigado, Quando é assim edite, é mais rápido que avisar.