# Verificar se variável foi definida

Tags: c++, funções, variáveis

Como faço para checar se uma variável foi definida?

O `#ifndef` pode ser usado para isso?

Sendo mais claro:

```
#include <iostream>

int getNumber()
{
    if (check)
        {
            check = false;
            return 10;
        }
    else
        {
            bool check = true;
            return 20;
        }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << getNumber() << endl;
    std::cout << getNumber() << endl;
    std::cout << getNumber() << endl;
}
```

Eu gostaria que retornasse:

```
20
10
20
```

Mas retorna o erro:

```
|5|error: 'check' was not declared in this scope|
```

A variável não pode ser definida na função `main()`, pois a função `getNumber()` será chamada em outros lugares também.

Comment: Eu já lhe falei para não alterar a pergunta que você fez antes. E para colocar exemplos, detalhar o que você quer desde o início. Você pode estar pensando que é a mesma pergunta. Mas quando você colocou o que você quer fazer, mudou a pergunta completamente. As respostas dadas antes não servem mais porque você perguntou originalmente uma coisa e você queria saber outra coisa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infelizmente a pergunta foi mudada e agora está perguntando outra coisa completamente diferente da original, vou deixar a resposta original abaixo

Até entendo que você está aprendendo mas o que você quer fazer exige estado e não dá para fazer de forma tão trivial. O código da resposta do Guilherme Nascimento funciona, se você rodar só este exemplo isolado. Se for usar dentro de uma aplicação mais complexa, você terá problemas.

Você terá que guardar a situação em alguma variável e essa variável terá que ser conhecida pela sua função de forma isolada. Se você usar uma variável global você terá problemas (veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513/101), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/925/101)).

Você pode criar uma classe ou pelo menos uma estrutura para fazer isso mas na verdade como é algo que não chega montar uma nova estrutura de dados não precisa tanto, pode fazer algo mais simples, algo assim:

```
#include <iostream>

int getNumber(bool &check) { //recebe o estado por referência
    if (check) {
        check = false;
        return 10;
    } else {
        check = true;
        return 20;
    }
}

int main() {
    bool numero = false;
    std::cout << getNumber(numero) << endl;
    std::cout << getNumber(numero) << endl;
    std::cout << getNumber(numero) << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jdU2xb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gzkdcedy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/Reference.cpp).

Eu sei que você vai achar mais complicado. Mas do que adianta algo simples e errado? Desta forma você pode ter quantos estados quiser. Se não fizer assim ou a função passa ter pouquíssima utilidade ou você vai ter que coordenar o uso dela, que é bem mais difícil que fazer isso.

Eu usei o parâmetro por referência assim qualquer alteração na variável `check` dentro da função altera também a variável que enviou o valor para a função, então a variável `numero` está sempre com o estado adequado para aquele momento.

Se desse para verificar se uma variável foi criada ou não, sua lógica não funcionaria a não ser que mandasse apagar a variável, o que não faz sentido. O próprio título da sua pergunta não faz sentido com a real pergunta atual.

Note que no ideone eu melhorei seu código.

Fiz um exemplo mais sofisticado. Não recomendo o uso da terceira forma já que usa uma variável estática, ou seja, estado global. Mas pelo menos está encapsulado em uma função, já ajuda.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Interleave {
    T a, b;
    bool check = false;
    public:
        Interleave(T a, T b) {
            this->a = a;
            this->b = b;
        }
    
        T getValue() {
            check = !check;
            return check ? a : b;
        }
};

int getNumber() {
    static Interleave<int> numero(10, 20);
    return numero.getValue();
}

int main() {
    Interleave<int> numero(10, 20);
    cout << numero.getValue() << endl;
    cout << numero.getValue() << endl;
    cout << numero.getValue() << endl;

    Interleave<string> texto("aaa", "bbb");
    cout << texto.getValue() << endl;
    cout << texto.getValue() << endl;
    cout << texto.getValue() << endl;

    cout << getNumber() << endl;
    cout << getNumber() << endl;
    cout << getNumber() << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fa3U6w). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rlqlzpqo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/Reference2.cpp).

---

C++ é uma linguagem compilada e de tipagem estática. Todas as variáveis devem existir em tempo de compilação. Ao contrário do que você está acostumado com linguagens dinâmicas, não é possível tratar variáveis como dados de forma direta.

Lembra [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44389/101)? Ali tem uma dica para simular as variáveis dinâmicas. No fundo as linguagens dinâmicas fazem mais ou menos aquele mapa que eu indiquei para você. Quando você está programando você tem a ilusão de estar usando variáveis mas no fundo está acessando posições nesses mapas também chamados de dicionários ou *hashes*.

Percebeu porque essas variáveis são dinâmicas e podem ou não existir? Porque elas são dados em pares de chave valor, onde a chave é o nome da variável e o valor é o que está guardado nessa "variável".

Mesmo algumas linguagens dinâmicas podem ter variáveis reais. Em geral variáveis locais são consideradas reais. Estas variáveis também devem existir sempre. Essas variáveis são preferíveis porque elas são mais garantidas pelo compilador e são mais rápidas.

Se você realmente tem um problema que a variável pode ou não existir, use um mapa e simule a variável. Em C++ não tem sintaxe que facilite o acesso como se fosse uma variável de verdade.

Mas provavelmente você pode fazer a mesma coisa de outra forma. Quando se está programando em linguagens estáticas tem que pensar de uma forma diferente.

A resposta do Guilherme Nascimento está correta, mas essas variáveis que ele está falando só existem no processo de compilação, elas não tem serventia na aplicação em si. Elas são usadas para ajudar compilar a aplicação e não para executá-la. E o seu uso é desincentivado sempre que possível (nem sempre é). Pense em duas linguagens diferentes que estão no mesmo código mas não se comunicam. Variável de pré-processador sequer fazem parte do C++.

Se ainda acha que precisa disso, formule uma pergunta dizendo onde quer chegar, quem sabe tenhamos uma solução melhor.

Comment: Obrigado por comentar, gostaria de deixar claro que respondi conforme exatamente o autor perguntou, ele precisava de acesso a variável FORA do "main" então por tanto não foi uma questão de exemplo que forneci, mas sim o que foi solicitado pelo autor: "PS: -A variável não pode ser definida na função main, pois a função getNumber será chamada em outros lugares também"

Comment: Sim, claro. Ele está com dificuldade até para fazer a pergunta, imagine o requisito correto. Variáveis globais não eram problema há 40, 50 anos quando os códigos eram bem pequenos. As linguagens modernas limitam o uso de a estado global em variável localizada. C++ tem variável global por legado mas não deve ser usada. Variáveis não devem ser usadas em "outros lugares", elas devem ser locais. Se os valores precisam ser usados em outros lugares, ok, mas aí deve-se passá-lo como parâmetro. Eu até uso estado global mas eu sei todas as implicações de fazer isto, é relativamente raro quem sabe.

Comment: Não foi sobre isso que eu me referi, mas talvez o meu esforço em tentar explicar já tenha se tornado em vão.

Answer (score 4):

Variáveis no C/C++ não podem ser usadas se não forem definidas, pois o compilador emitirá uma mensagem de erro e não será compilado o seu projeto, em outras palavras, não existe maneira de verificar se a variável foi definida, por que não há necessidade.

Conforme o seu exemplo, bastaria você definir a variável antes da função e remover o `bool` que está no `else`. Note que `bool check` está fora de `main()` para que você possa vir a acessar em outros lugares (conforme você mencionou no seu "PS."):

```
#include <iostream>

bool check;

int getNumber()
{
    if (check) {
        check = false;
        return 10;
    } else {
        check = true;
        return 20;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getNumber() << std::endl;
}
```

Você também pode criar uma classe, o que ajudaria a deixar a variável "isolada".

Porém como você postou o código `#ifndef` é usado para verificar se o MACRO foi definido (*isto não é uma variável*) e conforme Maniero citou, isto é só usado em tempo de compilação, portanto não tem o mesmo propósito das variáveis.

Leia sobre em: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion

Existem várias vantagens de usar os MACROS, uma é por que é obrigatório usarmos em arquivos "headers" (`.h` ou `.hpp`), para impedir que ocorra falhas acaso ele seja inserido mais de uma vez.

Também podemos usar para criar dois eventos ou operações para cada tipo de compilador:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
void MainWindow::test ()
{
   //trabalhar com MingW
}
#else
void MainWindow::test ()
{
   //Outro compilador
}
#endif
```

Você pode definir rapidamente em um arquivo global um MACRO para dizer se o aplicativo é de produção (está sendo usado pelas "pessoas") ou desenvolvimento (você está fazendo manutenção ou criando ele).

Portanto MACRO é diferente de variável (já que macro geralmente não tem variação em seus dados).