# Como listar as variáveis dentro de uma tabela em Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Por exemplo:

```
minion = {
   hp = 1000,
   x = 10,
   y = 25
}
```

Existe alguma função que eu possa saber quantas variáveis existem dentro desta tabela?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já há uma [resposta para o tamanho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33301/101). Para percorrer os elementos:

```
minion = {
    hp = 1000,
    x = 10,
    y = 25 }

for i, v in pairs(minion) do
    print(i, "=>", v)
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/fPoLJw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fyqzpdfo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ListTable.lua).